# Why don't I get the value from the text-node as I pass through the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the following script I attempt to move through the *DOM Tree* but I do not get the output I expect.

There is only a small piece of *html* in this :

```
<p id="para">This is inside the <em>p</em> tag.</p>
```

As I move through the tree this is what I get :

```
Node Name : P
Node Type : 1
Node Value : null


Node Name : HTML
Node Type : 1
Node Value : null
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <p id="para">This is inside the <em>p</em> tag.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function nodeStatus(node) {
            document.write("Node Name : " + node.nodeName + "<br />");
            document.write("Node Type : " + node.nodeType + "<br / >");
            document.write("Node Value : " + node.nodeValue + "<br / >");
            document.write("<br / > <br / >");
        }
        var curElement = document.getElementById("para");
        nodeStatus(curElement); // p tag
        curElement = document.firstChild; // This is inside the 
        nodeStatus(curElement);
        curElement = document.nextSibling; // em tag
        nodeStatus(curElement);
        curElement = document.firstChild; // p
        nodeStatus(curElement); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Why don't I get the value from the `text-node` ?

And what is that ***HTML*** that I get as a node name ? I haven't named any node as *HTML*.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HmkJQ/

Comment: Of course you have a `<html>` node. Have a look at the top of your document!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is starting over from the top-level document in each line of code. You start out with:

```
var curElement = document.getElementById("para");
```

And you get the p element as expected. But then you try to get the child of the p element, but using this code

```
curElement = document.firstChild;
```

what you get is the first child of the **document** itself (and that means the root html element!).

Instead, you should navigate as follows:

```
curElement = curElement.firstChild;
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The node of NodeName `HTML` is the `<html>` element, ie `document.firstChild`. You're not getting any text nodes because you're iterating through HTML elements, ie DOM element nodes. [A bit more on this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).

Your code itself deals with a variable called `curElement`, which suggests you're expecting these to be element nodes and not their contents.

To get nodes that sit *within* element nodes, you might want to grab the `childNodes` of any given `curElement`.